# vba FOR to validate color of cells in a range

Tags: excel, validation, loops, colors, vba

I am doing a macro to check and validate all cells by colorindex. kindly help me if there is wrong in my code. Many Thanks.

```
    Sub Validate()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("CATALOG!B2:F98")
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Boolean

i = False

For Each cel In rng
With cel
    If .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        If .EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            i = True
        End If
    End If
   End With
   Next cel

 If i = True Then
  MsgBox "yellow"
Else
  MsgBox "none"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Do you get error or what? I can tell that you would only run 1 cell no matter what, since you `Exit Sub` in both part of your `IF..ELSE`. I would assume if you enter the `Else` statement it's okay and therefor you don't exit the sub.

Comment: You don't need to reapet 'cel' inside your 'With-statement. I also think you want to remove the two 'Exit Sub', but perhaps that is what you want? Also, you can use 'For Each cel in rng', so without .Cells...

Comment: Hi. Thank you for that. Please see my code now. but my problem now is that the prompt says yellow but I have no longer yellow cells, I am afraid that it detects also the hidden cells. how can I incorporate only the active cells and disregards the value of hidden ones. thanks

Comment: Add a check to your If-statement, so that `If .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then` becomes `If .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 and not (.entirerow.Hidden or .entirecolumn.Hidden) Then`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what you're asking, but there are two ways:

1) first, when you want to check if every cell in range has `.Interior.ColorIndex = 6`. Then your code should look like:

```
Sub Validate()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("CATALOG!B2:F98")
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Boolean

i = True
For Each cel In rng.Cells
    If Not cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        i = False
        Exit For 'we found cell with different color, so we can exit loop
    End If
Next cel

If i = True Then
    MsgBox "yellow"
Else
    MsgBox "none"
End If

End Sub
```

2) you want to check if any cell has `.Interior.ColorIndex = 6`. Then it should look like:

```
Sub Validate()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("CATALOG!B2:F98")
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Boolean

i = False
For Each cel In rng.Cells
    If cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        i = True
        Exit For 'we found cell with the color, so we can exit loop
    End If
Next cel

If i = True Then
    MsgBox "yellow"
Else
    MsgBox "none"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: hi. please see my code above.. it is still not accurate. it prompts "yellow" even though i have no longer yellow on the visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

Of what I've gatered you are trying to loop through all non hidden cells and see if they have a yellow background color, and if they are yellow they need to change based on a input.

```
Sub Validate()

Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("CATALOG!B1:F98")
Dim cel As Range

For Each cel In rng
    With cel
        If .Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            If .EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                .Interior.ColorIndex = InputBox("please input new colorIndex", "SetColorIndex")
            End If
        End If
   End With
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: hi. please see my code above.. it is still not accurate. it prompts "yellow" even though i have no longer yellow on the visible cells.

Comment: Do you want the promt? Else you have a yellow color that dont correspond with ColorIndex 6. My code do not prompt the yellow(ColorIndex 6) background if it's within a hidden row.